# How to import a specific .py file far into my directory

Tags: python, directory

I have a file called connector.py deep in my project directory. How do I import it correctly? I'll give you my directory from my project:

```
/myproject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py
```

I tried some steps on the internet but that would not work. Do I need to import specific libraries in order for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below import for importing this module

```
from aiohttp import connector
```

Just make sure that you using the correct environment.

Comment: The issue is that it does not let me import many folders in...

Comment: for importing any folder your python path should contain the address of that. You can use sys.path for listing all the available path for importing modules.

Comment: You can refer the official docs for this library. https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/

Comment: I meant: How should I refer to the file and then reset so it works normally?

Comment: Sorry, it is late for me and I was confusing ideas. It works just fine now, thank you!